# How to retrieve edge value/label in vis.js?

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I am manipulating nodes and edges after graph generated.I wanted to retrieve the edges value or title during double click on edges.

```
nodes = [{id: 'TEST1',  value: 0, label: 'TEST1', title: TEST1'},
         {id: 'engine',  value: 0, label: 'engine', title: 'engine'}];

  // create connections between people
  // value corresponds with the amount of contact between two people
   edges = [{from: 'TEST1', to: 'engine', value: 4, title: '4 Connections'},];
```

I am able to get the value of node during double click on nodes with the following code.

```
network.on( 'doubleClick', function(properties) {
         alert('clicked node ' + properties.nodes[0]);
});
```

How to retrieve the value of edges?

Answer (score 1):

**HOW TO RETRIEVE EDGE / NODES PROPERTIES IN VIS.JS WHEN USING DOUBLE CLICK EVENT**

To properly identify single node, single edge, or node with an edge

when the event is `doubleClick` you can use try this.

```
 network.on('doubleClick', function(properties) {


    var nodeIDs = properties.nodes;
    clickedNodes = nodes.get(nodeIDs);

    var edgesIDs = properties.edges;
    clickedEdges = edges.get(edgesIDs);

    var clickedType = 0;
    if (typeof clickedEdges != "undefined" &&
        clickedEdges != null &&
        clickedEdges.length != null &&
        clickedEdges.length > 0) {

        console.log("Edge:" + clickedEdges);
        clickedType = 2;

    }

    if (typeof clickedNodes != "undefined" &&
        clickedNodes != null &&
        clickedNodes.length != null &&
        clickedNodes.length > 0) {

        console.log("Node:" + clickedNodes);
        clickedType++;
    }
    //NODE ONLY
    if (clickedType == 1 ) {
      
        console.log(clickedNodes[0].id);
        //Do you Jquery here for Nodes
    }
    //EDGE ONLY
    if (clickedType == 2) {
       
        console.log(clickedEdges[0].id);
        console.log(clickedEdges[0].label);
         //Do you Jquery here for Edge

    };
    //NODE WITH EDGE
    if (clickedType == 3) {
        alert("single node or with edge ");
        console.log(clickedNodes[0].id);
        console.log(clickedEdges[0].id);
        //Do you Jquery here for Nodes
    }


});
```

on your object, you can add whatever additional property key/name and used them.

```
clickedNodes[0].id;
clickedNodes[0].device;

clickedEdges[0].id;
clickedNodes[0].ipaddress;
```

Answer (score 0):

The events like `doubleClick` provide you a list with the id's of edges. If your edges don't have an id, Network generates one for them internally, but you will not be able to match them in your original data.

Best is to create your data in a `DataSet`, and give the edges an id:

```
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
  {id: 'TEST1',  value: 0, label: 'TEST1', title: 'TEST1'},
  {id: 'engine',  value: 0, label: 'engine', title: 'engine'}
]);

var edges = new vis.DataSet([
  {id: 1, from: 'TEST1', to: 'engine', value: 4, title: '4 Connections'}
]);

network.on( 'doubleClick', function(properties) {
  var nodeIds = properties.nodes;
  console.log('node ids:', nodeIds);
  console.log('nodes:', nodes.get(nodeIds));

  var edgeIds = properties.edges;
  console.log('edge ids:', edgeIds);
  console.log('edges:', edges.get(edgeIds));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary to the answer stating that your edges should have explicit ids to be findable, they just don't have to.

You should just use the `DataSet`'s `get` method to find the element by it's id, it works for internal ids, too.

```
network.on( 'doubleClick', function(properties) {

     // selected edge id
     var edgeId = properties.edges[0];

     // find corresponding edge
     var edge = edges.get( edgeId );

     if ( edge ) {

        // found one!
        var from = edge.from;
        var   to = edge.to;

     }
});
```